# Doubt in a question in Newton's Laws of Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

The following question is from JEE (Joint Entrance Examination) 2007.

[image: Problem Image]

As it is clear from the solution of the problem, they have included only the horizontal component of acceleration and not the vertical component.

Before looking at the solution, I was confused whether to include the vertical component of acceleration or not. So, I decided to solve by using the options. I just imagined the following to solve the problem:

As time passes the two particles come stick together (let's neglect they will oscillate due to the collision). Then we can consider the two particles as a single particle of mass ***2m***. Now by using 2nd Newton's Law of Motion, we can compute the vertical acceleration (now there is no horizontal component) to be F/(2m). Now let us substitute x=0 in the options and hope for the result acceleration is F/(2m). This happens only with option A. But it is incorrect. Please explain how to attempt this question.

OPTIONAL:
For your kind information the solution of the problem is given by FIITJEE and the link for the solution is [THIS](http://cms.fiitjee.co/Resources/DownloadCentre/Document_Pdf_38.pdf)
Refer: Page No. 3; Question 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought about whether to include vertical acceleration is a good consideration. Let's examine that. If there is vertical acceleration of the particles, they have left the horizontal surface and the normal force is zero. Then the weight force will accelerate them downward and the string will constrain them to swing on an inward arc. If the balls aren't high enough then fall back to the surface. So, in the limit of smooth (infinitesimal) motions, the balls don't accelerate vertically until they are touching and can't swing inward. Therefore, as long as they are separate, the only acceleration to consider is the horizontal acceleration.

You jumped immediately to the non-separate case, but the problem asked about the separation case.

Part of solving physics problems is asking about possibilities (here, vertical and horizontal components of acceleration), but also following through to see if the possibility (vertical component) needs mathematical analysis.

Comment: By the term vertical acceleration, I meant to say the acceleration of the particles along the direction of force. Further, I considered the given diagram as the top view of the system under consideration, since they did not include the surface. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @GuruVishnu The problem specifically and clearly states that the force F acts vertically. That means that the view given is definitely a side view, not a top view. They didn't show the surface because the text of the problem is unambiguous. Trust the words, and let them interpret the diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The problem makes clear that the particles are still on the surface. There is no vertical acceleration therefore. The upward force on the particles is being *assumed* (this is why  the word "small" appears in the question) to be less than the weight of the objects.  The upwards normal force exerted by the frictionless surface is reduced by the force $F$ so that  the downwards weight, upward force $F$, and the normal force $N$   add up to zero.

Comment: By the term vertical acceleration, I meant to say the acceleration of the particles along the direction of force. Further, I considered the given diagram as the top view of the system under consideration, since they did not include the surface. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think you probably misread the question. The force F is not acting into the plane of the paper, but rather vertically upward itself.

Answer (score 0):

As it is given the two balls are touching  the surface hence there is  no need to talk about vertical acceleration ,in the question we have to consider that case only if it left the surface then vertical force mg try to pull it downward.then we have to think about the vertical acceleration .